# Yii2 dektrium user registration with 3 options

Tags: yii2, user-registration

I tried to found answer on google but without success. What i want to say with this title is: I have ordinary user, doctor(for example) and hospital(for example). As i know when i register an user the information goes to my `profile` table.But if i register a doctor i want the information to be saved in my `doctor_profile` table. Same with the hospital registration. I can make difference between registration types by `$flag`(1, 2 or 3). So what i want to understand is is it possible to redirect doctor information to `doctor_profile`.Hospital => `hospital_profile`.
I hope i explain it well. Tons of thanks and appreciating any advice if that plan is not a good idea :)

Comment: You  have some code  .. o rIs a theoretical question? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily log in using different submissions and POSTs (eg using different buttons) that call for different controller / action links that handle the data in POST appropriately. This essentially depends on how you intend to design the application and its registration form (s).